# Deserialize is giving warning Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type

Tags: c#

I am getting a below warning in visual studio 2022 for line `(T)ser.Deserialize(sr)` in the below code.

Warning:

> Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type.

Code:

```
public T Deserialize<T>(string input) where T : class
{
    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer ser = new 
      System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

    using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(input))
    {
        return (T)ser.Deserialize(sr);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to get rid of this warning?

Comment: `XmlSerializer.Deserialize` returns a nullable object. Change the method to return `T?` and the last line to cast to `T?` also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XmlSerializer.Deserialize` returns a nullable object so your method should also do that. Change the method to return `T?` and the last line to cast to `T?` also:

```
public T? Deserialize<T>(string input) where T : class
{
    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer ser = new
      System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

    using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(input))
    {
        return (T?)ser.Deserialize(sr);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can check for null and maybe throw an exception or do something else if the return is null:

```
public T Deserialize<T>(string input) where T : class
{
    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer ser = new
      System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

    using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(input))
    {
        var t = ser.Deserialize(sr);
        if(t == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("It was null, panic!");
        }
        return (T)t;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using .net6/c#10, that's a new feature in c#10([also u can see this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/nullable-warnings)). Compiler always checking for possible null values. That's why it's giving you these warnings. To simply fix that you can just make method return `nullable<T>` instead of just `T`. Also using statement and serializer declaration can be simplified with new syntactic sugar since .net5/c#9

```
public T? Deserialize<T>(string input) where T : class
{
    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer ser = new(typeof(T));

    using StringReader sr = new StringReader(input);
    return ser.Deserialize(sr) as T;
}
```